# Proper Data Type for PHP MySQL Phone Number?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table in PHP for a telephone directory database but I keep getting

> Error code 1264: Out of range value for column 'number' at row 1

when I try to submit a 10 digit phone number.

I tried changing it from `BIGINT` to `VARCHAR` but it still throws an error.

How can I fix this?

Here is my create table code:

```php
$SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE $TableName(countID SMALLINT 
    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40), last_name VARCHAR(40), address VARCHAR(100), city VARCHAR(40), state 
    VARCHAR(40), zip INT, number VARCHAR(40))";
```

Comment: I guess `number` is actually the `phoneNo`?

Comment: I think the problem is I used "number" for the variable name. It is supposed to be the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked, and yes, `number` is a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), so you cannot use it as a column name.

If you use it for a column name you have to use back ticks around it, or using something like `PhoneNo`.

It's best to store phone numbers and ZIP codes in strings. This would also keep the right amount of zero's at the front.

Answer (score 0):

number is not a variable name. You try phoneNumber or anything